# Access time puppeteer screenshot is captured?

Tags: node.js, screenshot, puppeteer

I am taking multiple screenshots using puppeteer and running multiple threads to speed up processing time but am struggling to find a way to retain the original frame order.

There are two factors making this tricky:

1. Puppeteer takes screenshot2 as soon as screenshot1 has finished resulting in irregular intervals between screenshots.
2. screenshot2 can actually be processed quicker than screenshots but we don't have anyway of accessing this duration or a timestamp at which time the screenshot is captured.

I was hoping there would be an event fired or this info exposed through the Buffer but unless I've missed something I don't think these are options.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: When you create a new thread you are opening a new page?. Just remember that puppeteer use awaits so, in fact, screenshot2 always will be take as soon as screenshot1 finish.

Comment: yep i am familiar with async and await but using more than one thread is causing a problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Node.js function [`fs.statSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path_options) to get the timestamp that the screenshot was accessed, modified, changed, or created.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let screenshot_path = '/var/www/example.com/public_html/example.png';

await page.screenshot({
  path: screenshot_path,
});

let screenshot_stats = fs.statSync(screenshot_path);

console.log(screenshot_stats.atime); // Access Time
console.log(screenshot_stats.mtime); // Modification Time
console.log(screenshot_stats.ctime); // Change Time
console.log(screenshot_stats.birthtime); // Birth Time
```